# Android Google Maps only works with Android Studio 0.8.6 run

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I've written a simple app which utilises the map fragment template in Android Studio 0.8.6. It manages to load the map whenever I've connected the device to the computer and run it straight from Android Studio. However, the map doesn't load if I export as signed apk (app-release with master db encryption) and install it onto the phone directly (failed to contact Google server error). Any ideas as to why? Obviously I cannot release onto the Play Store if the only way it works is by installing via Android Studio.

(Basically Maps v2 only works through the ADB install and not the APK.)

Tested on three separate devices. All work when connected to computer and installed but none of them load map after reinstallation from apk. Generated a lot of keys which doesn't seem to be the issue.

EDIT: Unrelated issue but in case anyone is looking for it but Android Studio didn't build the latest version and I fixed this by reinstalling Android Studio. Actually quite an easy fix for some problems so I recommend trying this. Going to try and see if it fixed the original issue.

Comment: Did you add all keys you used for signing to the Google API Console?

Comment: @pjco yes, I added to my API key permission both the SHA1s on the debug.keystore on my computer and the final keystore I use to sign the APK

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally got it to work by selecting build type: debug in Android Studio instead of release. I still think there's an issue with the key despite me trying multiple keystores and keys with both the debug.keystore and final keystore but at least this works now. Message me for more details.

EDIT: I just discovered that I was putting the key in the xml file under debug and completely missed the identical file in the folder under the release key. Hope this clears things up for whoever missed this also.